# Weird behavior with "Wrap Text" in tables

Tags: google-docs, formatting

I'm trying to add an image at the beginning of cell of a table that *Wraps text* however, for some bizarre reason it seems also block out space in the cell to the right.

[image: Weird Google Docs]

Where as, I'd expect something that looks like:

[image: Nice Google Docs]

[Here's my example document.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qncJePh4iRrtAewUDp7vSMyO-oS0tsqkb4mNLI2vCk4/edit?usp=sharing)  Is this a bug?  If so is it documented anywhere or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like its some kind of a bug, but it can be resolved as tested:

- click on the image
- select **In line**
- then select **wrap text**
- done

[image]

Comment: Nice Gif!  But now I have a different issue where I can't get rid of [this space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlFZj.png) below the image.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock np. click on image > select margin 0mm > then place cursor before "John" and press "CTRL+]" and add spaces as needed > then place cursor before "But" and again pres "CTRL+]" and add spaces with spacebar key